# using staggered gridlayout manager in recycler view sorting of items in particulate order is possible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I have recyclerview which is displaying lot of items in card views those views are dynamic height like following pic.
[image]

I achieved it but i have an other problem if i apply any order like increase like that iam getting this one.

[image]

If we look in 5th and 6th cards are not following order.it is disturbing UI.
i know it is happening because of Staggered.

Is there any way without disturbing staggered we can achieve ordering also.

Comment: They are actually following order. `5` enters screen before `6`

Comment: yes i know but end user can't understand.user will expected 5 before 6.

Comment: @akash93 that is the problem i am facing.as per ui user think 6 is first coming order misssing.

Comment: Don't think there's a built in way to solve this. Btw I checked G+ app which also uses this layout and the behaviour is exactly the same. Don't understand how it can be conceived as wrong order

Comment: @akash93 i know that is there any possibility to customize layout manager?

Comment: Yes you can create your own layout manager extending `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` but it will require a lot of effort . Maybe if this happens for all your items you're better off implementing an RTL layout for this scenario as a hack

Comment: @akash93 can you provide to customize StaggeredGridLayoutManager.I am new to this concept.if you know any links plz post it,those will helpful for me.