# StaggeredGridLayoutManager items in adjacent columns swapping positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, staggered-gridview

I am using a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to layout `Cardviews`, where each card has a button which can expand and contract the card to show different information. The cards are laid out in two columns vertically across the screen. The cards are backed by a `RealmObject` and I am using a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` to lay them out in the recycler view but I don't think that is the problem.

When I tap on a button which causes `onBindViewHolder()` to be called, occasionally my cards will swap places across the columns. Only cards that are in adjacent columns swap and I can show this by increasing the number of columns to three or four and watching the behaviour. By changing the number of columns to one the cards stop swapping. There is a nice animation when the cards swap with eachother but if I turn off the animations (`recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)`) the cards still swap just without the animation.

The cards only swap position when `onBindViewHolder()` is called and it happens often enough to be obvious but I am not able to replicate the functionality, it seems to happen randomly.

Here is some code:

Fragment that displays the `RecyclerView`:

```
public class DeviceCardListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RealmResults<Bank> deviceList;

    public int locationId = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        //Turn off the blinking animation when the Realm Refreshes
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
        if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
            ((SimpleItemAnimator)animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }

        StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        manager.setGapStrategy(GAP_HANDLING_NONE);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new StaggeredDeviceAdapter(getContext(), deviceList));
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(40);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

`StaggeredDeviceAdapter`:

```
public class StaggeredDeviceAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Bank, StaggeredDeviceViewHolder> {
    private RealmResults<Bank> devices;
    private Context context;

    public StaggeredDeviceAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Bank> list) {
        super(list, true);
        this.devices = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public StaggeredDeviceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.device_card, null);

        //setHasStableIds(true);
        StaggeredDeviceViewHolder holder = new StaggeredDeviceViewHolder(layoutView);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StaggeredDeviceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setValues(devices.get(position), context);
    }
}
```

`StaggeredDeviceViewHolder`:

I have pulled out my actual view configuration into another class for reusability which is quite large but I don't think anything in there is important.

```
public class StaggeredDeviceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View view;

    DeviceCardHolder holder;

    public StaggeredDeviceViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        holder = new DeviceCardHolder(view, false);
        //holder.initialise();

        this.view = view;
    }

    //Called from outside the class
    //Sets all of the fields to whatever values we want
    public void setValues(Bank bank, Context context) {
        holder.initialise();
        holder.setValues(bank, context);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you want any other information from me.

EDIT:
Adding Realm Information

```
 deviceList = realm.where(Bank.class).equalTo("locationSection",location).findAllSorted("locationID");
```

None of those fields are being changed in code, in fact they don't even have setters. 
Because the realm is sorted and the cards only swap along the horizontal axis makes me think that the issue is with the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` rather than Realm.

EDIT:
Through additional testing I have been able to reliably replicate the issue.

I am using a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` because my cards can change size. This is done by pressing a button on the card. Expanding and returning the card to its original size does not cause `onBindViewHolder()` to be called. The cards below the ones who's size is changing swap columns when `onBindViewHolder()` is called after one of the cards has changed size. The cards don't swap every time but I would say it happens around 80% of the time. Only cards directly underneath the ones I am manipulating swap positions.
This makes me think that the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` is getting confused as to where its indexes are supposed to be when the cards change size, maybe there is a setting about indexes that I am missing....

EDIT:
The issue I am having is basically the same one outlined in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241048/):

… but it doesn't have an answer

Comment: How is `deviceList` initialized?

Comment: If you don't sort the `deviceList`, the order might not be stable. Try to use `findAllSortedAsync()`/`findAllSorted()` instead.

Comment: I have edited the question with information about the `RealmResults`

Comment: `locationID` is not the primary key so it is not unique. The sort orders might be different from time to time if you have objects with duplicated `locationID`. Try to add more sorter conditions to make sure the sort order is stable.

Comment: I have updated the query to sort by primary keys and other additional fields but am still having the same issue. I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: The problem I am having is outlined in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241048/using-staggered-gridlayout-manager-in-recycler-view-sorting-of-items-in-particul but it doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Hi @Rev just like ur problem i am also have same issue.As SGLM default behavior it will adjust the cards according to the it's size.For example if we take ur 1st card height is grater than ur 2nd card there will be space 3rd card will place below of 2nd card.Like this when ur pressing button card's resizing will happen and cards places will modified it is it's default behavior.